# How can i delete a bookmark using docx4j?

Tags: java, templates, docx, bookmarks, docx4j

Strange thing. I'm trying to delete a "_GoBack" bookmark in a docx file, because it's ruining VariablePrepare (interesting, but different topic). I have a very simple template, and there is only one bookmark, which is:

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
```

It appears anytime i make a change in the template, in the place of the last change.

This code:

```
MainDocumentPart main = docx.getMainDocumentPart();
List<Object> bmList = getAllElementFromObject(main, CTBookmark.class);
CTBookmark bm = (CTBookmark) bmList.get(0);
System.out.println(bm.getName());
```

gives me **"_GoBack"**, so i'm sure that the bookmark is found correctly. But strangely if i do this:

```
getAllElementFromObject(main, CTBookmark.class).remove(0);
```

the bookmark doesn't get deleted. To check, this code:

```
System.out.println(getAllElementFromObject(main, CTBookmark.class).size());
getAllElementFromObject(main, CTBookmark.class).remove(0);
System.out.println(getAllElementFromObject(main, CTBookmark.class).size());
```

returns

```
1
1
```

Should i use some other approach to delete a bookmark in docx4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide the code for your method getAllElementFromObject, but I guess it doesn't find a CTBookmark object which is wrapped in a JAXB element.

From the [BookmarksDeleter.java sample](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/BookmarksDeleter.java):

```
    // Can't just remove the object from the parent,
    // since in the parent, it may be wrapped in a JAXBElement
    for (Object ox : theList) {
    if (XmlUtils.unwrap(ox).equals(bm)) {
        return theList.remove(ox);
    }
```

You also need to handle CTMarkupRange?

So yeah, to delete bookmarks using docx4j, see the linked sample, or try [RangeFinder.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/finders/RangeFinder.java)

Comment: Hi Jason, I'm facing the same issue which Emptyfruit stated as a different topic. I mean I'm not able merge those runs using variable prepare. Can I know how the document knows _goback bookmark was there. Is there any solution for that!

Comment: Actually I deleted the _goback bookmark yet I'm not able to merge those runs using variable prepare.

Comment: You should make your own question, and include the relevant XML